# Why does sqldf convert datetime to local in R while data.table doesn't?

Tags: sql, r, data.table, sqldf

Following simple code:

```
library(sqldf)
library(data.table)

OwnerUserId <- c(24612)
CreationDate <- c("2016-05-27 03:17:41")

DataTable <- data.table(OwnerUserId, CreationDate)

write.csv(DataTable, "DataTable.csv")

DataTable <- fread("DataTable.csv", stringsAsFactors = TRUE)

sqldf("
    SELECT OwnerUserId, CreationDate
    FROM DataTable
    WHERE OwnerUserId == 24612
  ")

DataTable[OwnerUserId == 24612, .(OwnerUserId, CreationDate),]
```

produces following output:

```
  OwnerUserId        CreationDate
1       24612 2016-05-27 09:17:41

> DataTable[OwnerUserId == 24612, .(OwnerUserId, CreationDate),]
   OwnerUserId        CreationDate
1:       24612 2016-05-27 03:17:41
```

I'm just curious if this behavior is expected.
If yes, then how can we get same result via sqldf and data.table?

Comment: See https://github.com/ggrothendieck/sqldf/issues/10

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Yes, "Sys.setenv(TZ = "UTC")" solves the proplem. I also tried this right after asking this question. However, there will be another problem connected with the type missmatch (local vs UTC types). Anyway, this is another story. Thank you for this comment!

Comment: Be sure you read the entire thread.  Sys.setenv was only one of the solutions.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Now I read entire thread. A lot of workarounds. Thanks twice!

Answer (score 0):

The contents of the csv, note that there's no mention of any timezone

```
# "","OwnerUserId","CreationDate"
# "1",24612,"2016-05-27 03:17:41"
```

When you read it in, fread takes it as a factor because it's just a string and you didn't give it any reason to think otherwise.

```
DataTable <- fread("DataTable.csv", stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
DataTable[, str(CreationDate)]
# Factor w/ 1 level "2016-05-27 03:17:41": 1
```

When I run sqldf, I get exactly what I would expect, and it's identical to data.table.

```
sqldf("
    SELECT OwnerUserId, CreationDate
    FROM DataTable
    WHERE OwnerUserId == 24612
  ")
#   OwnerUserId        CreationDate
# 1       24612 2016-05-27 03:17:41
```

If I had to guess, my money would be on it having been changed somewhere by reference. Can you run the code here on fresh R session and see if you still get the same results?

Edit: Also check out what `getOption("sqldf.method")` returns for you. It's possible that it's using "name__class", but even that would be unlikely to produce this result.

Comment: Thanks for your unswer. As I understand, you cannot reproduce mentioned problem. I've checked one more time after restarting R session (IDE was restarted). Copy-pasted SO code into the newly created file. The same problem appear. getOption("sqldf.method") simply returns NULL. I guess your PC uses "GMT+0" that is why you cannot reproduce the problem.

Comment: I don't think that's the cause. There's in fact never a time where the string becomes a date for me. It remains a string or a factor from creation, and both sqldf and data.table return a string when called. If something is causing the string to become a date, that's what you'll need to find.

Comment: I got you point. Thanks! Anyway, it is incredibly strange, that the same code gives different results for you and me. Let me ask you which version of R are you using. My R's revision is: version.string R version - 4.0.5 (2021-03-31), svn rev - 80133.